# WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().IsSystem in C++

Tags: c++, windows

I need to know if the current process is running as system. In C# I use `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().IsSystem` to do that, what is the equivalent in C++?

I'm trying to avoid comparing usernames, because different OS has different usernames for SYSTEM account.

Comment: Here's a possible sequence of calls: [`OpenProcessToken`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-openprocesstoken), [`GetTokenInformation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/securitybaseapi/nf-securitybaseapi-gettokeninformation): `TokenUser`, [`IsWellKnownSid`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/securitybaseapi/nf-securitybaseapi-iswellknownsid): `WinLocalSystemSid`.

Comment: @ErykSun TokenUser contains SID_AND_ATTRIBUTES instead of PSID structure, any ideas?

Comment: If the pointer to the `TOKEN_USER` record is `pTokenUser`, then the PSID is `pTokenUser->User.Sid`.

Answer (score 2):

I have created an example based on Eryk's idea, and it works:

```
BOOL IsSystem()
{
    HANDLE hToken = NULL;
    BOOL result = false;
    TOKEN_USER *tokenUser = NULL;
    DWORD dwLength = 0;

    if (OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_QUERY, &hToken) == 0)
    {
        DbgPrint("OpenProcessToken(): %d", GetLastError());
        goto cleanup;
    }

    if (GetTokenInformation(hToken, TokenUser, (LPVOID) tokenUser, 0, &dwLength) == 0)
    {
        if (GetLastError() != ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER)
        {
            DbgPrint("GetTokenInformation(): %d", GetLastError());
            goto cleanup;
        }

        tokenUser = (TOKEN_USER *) HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, dwLength);
        if (tokenUser == NULL)
        {
            goto cleanup;
        }

        if (GetTokenInformation(hToken, TokenUser, (LPVOID) tokenUser, dwLength, &dwLength) == 0)
        {
            DbgPrint("GetTokenInformation(): %d", GetLastError());
            goto cleanup;
        }

        result = IsWellKnownSid(tokenUser->User.Sid, WinLocalSystemSid);
    }

cleanup:
    if (tokenUser != NULL)
    {
        HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), NULL, tokenUser);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: This `goto` looks 

Comment: Not using `goto`. You know, like using `if` and `else` instead. Or [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization) e.g.

Comment: An exit/cleanup label that frees resources (e.g. handles, heap allocations) is normal in C, but not C++. That said, despite being tagged C++, and except for using `false`, this code is just C.